# Two forms how to distinguish each?

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {


    }
?>



<form action = "" method = "post">

    <label>Name of fruit</label><br>
    <input type = "text" name = "fruit" class = "box" placeholder="Enter Fruit"/><br><br>
    <input type = "submit" value = " Submit "/><br>

</form>


<form action = "" method = "post">

    <label>Name of pet</label><br>
    <input type = "text" name = "pet" class = "box" placeholder="Enter Pet"/><br><br>
    <input type = "submit" value = " Submit "/><br>       

</form>
```

Consider I have two forms and they behave differently. As in I click submit on the fruit one I expect another result than that of submit from the pet form. Normally If I had one form i'd just use the above php if statement but this wouldn't work with two.

So like if(_post['fruit']) -> something if(_post['pet']) -> something.

Is there a mechanism like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try ajax Call for this and also try by giving button names and procced as button press.

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['form1'])) {
        //
    }

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['form2'])) {
        //
    }
?>


<form action = "" method = "post">
    <label>Name of fruit</label><br>
    <input type = "text" name = "fruit" class = "box" placeholder="Enter Fruit"/><br><br>
    <input type = "submit" name="form1" value = " Submit "/><br>
</form>


<form action = "" method = "post">
    <label>Name of pet</label><br>
    <input type = "text" name = "pet" class = "box" placeholder="Enter Pet"/><br><br>
    <input type = "submit" name ="form2" value = " Submit "/><br>       
</form>
```

Comment: Glad to help. ! @et if this helps and worked you can mark this as answer.

Comment: Sorry for the wait just got back